# imagemagick: Remove all occurrences of a stray pixel surrounded by transparency

Tags: image-processing, command-line, imagemagick

**Hello!** I'd like to remove all occurrences of stray pixels from a transparent image.

Below is an example image, enlarged for convenience:

[image: Before Processing]

Following is that same image but how I desire it to look after processing:

[image: After Processing]

The best way I can think to describe what I'm looking to achieve is that every pixel whose surrounding pixels are fully transparent should be removed. Think of the selector as a 3x3 grid, with the middle of the grid being the pixel operated on.

I took a look at [Morphology](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/#basic) in the IM manual, but it doesn't appear to provide a fine enough method for this.

Is this possible with ImageMagick? Is there any other command line software that could achieve this if not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Imagemagick, you can use -connected-components to remove those isolated blocks of pixels. They seem to be 5x5 pixels on a side. So we threshold the area to keep at 26. We remove those blocks in the alpha channel and then replace that in the image. (Note we need to use 8-connected vs 4-connected region detection to preserve your other regions).

Since you say the your image was enlarged, so I presume your isolated regions were 1x1 pixels. So change the area-threshold to 2, to remove single pixel regions.

Input:

[image]

Unix Syntax:

```
convert img.png \
\( -clone 0 -alpha extract -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=26 \
-connected-components 8 \) \
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite \
result.png
```

[image]

Windows Syntax:

```
convert img.png ^
( -clone 0 -alpha extract -type bilevel ^
-define connected-components:mean-color=true ^
-define connected-components:area-threshold=26 ^
-connected-components 8 ) ^
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite ^
result.png
```

See [-connected-components](https://imagemagick.org/script/connected-components.php)

ADDITION:

If you only want to remove the small isolated color pixels and not any transparent pixels inside the color ones, then there is no trivial way to do that. That is an enhancement I would like to have. However, it can be done.

Here is your image modified so that the top left red block has a single transparent center pixel. I added a red line to its right to be sure it was larger than 25 pixels when the center was turned transparent and so that you could see which pixel has the transparent center. You will have to download and zoom in on this image to see the missing pixel.

[image]

4x Zoom:

[image]

The method is to find all white regions in the alpha channel and then make a list of all regions that are less than 26 pixels. Then reprocess the image to remove those regions by ID.

**Get ID List**

```
id_list=""
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
arr=(`convert img2.png -alpha extract -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-connected-components 8 null: | grep "gray(255)" | sed 's/^[ ]*//'`)
echo "${arr[*]}"
num=${#arr[*]}
IFS=$OLDIFS
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
id=`echo "${arr[$i]}" | cut -d' ' -f1 | sed 's/[:]*$//'`
count=`echo "${arr[$i]}" | cut -d' ' -f4`
if [ $count -lt 26 ]; then
id_list="$id_list $id"
fi
done
echo "$id_list"
```

Here is what is printed

```
12: 5x5+120+70 122.0,72.0 25 gray(255)
14: 5x5+30+85 32.0,87.0 25 gray(255)
15: 5x5+110+85 112.0,87.0 25 gray(255)
16: 5x5+75+90 77.0,92.0 25 gray(255)
17: 5x5+40+100 42.0,102.0 25 gray(255)
18: 5x5+110+110 112.0,112.0 25 gray(255)
19: 5x5+140+110 142.0,112.0 25 gray(255)
21: 5x5+15+130 17.0,132.0 25 gray(255)
22: 5x5+40+140 42.0,142.0 25 gray(255)
23: 5x5+85+140 87.0,142.0 25 gray(255)
24: 5x5+120+140 122.0,142.0 25 gray(255)
2: 5x5+55+5 57.0,7.0 25 gray(255)
5: 5x5+100+20 102.0,22.0 25 gray(255)
7: 5x5+65+30 67.0,32.0 25 gray(255)
8: 5x5+125+30 127.0,32.0 25 gray(255)
9: 5x5+105+50 107.0,52.0 25 gray(255)
11: 5x5+25+65 27.0,67.0 25 gray(255)

12 14 15 16 17 18 19 21 22 23 24 2 5 7 8 9 11
```

**Reprocess to remove regions by ID**

```
convert img2.png \
\( -clone 0 -alpha extract -type bilevel \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-define connected-components:remove="$id_list" \
-connected-components 8 -background black -flatten +write tmp.png \) \
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite \
result2.png
```

[image]

4x Zoom:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for response, I'm unable to replicate your results however. result.png outputs as a BW mask, presumably to be used in another magick command. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: What is your Imagemagick version and platform? My code was in  Unix syntax. Also be sure there are no spaces after the \.

Comment: Windows, I'm afraid. I adjusted the syntax accordingly, removing nothing but the backslashes and closing brackets. It executed without error but gave the aforementioned unexpected result. I suppose worst case scenario I end up dual-booting Ubuntu again for the first time in a few years.

Comment: See changes in my answer for Windows syntax. Also see the note about your resizing the input. Also please supply your IM version as I asked. You may be on too old a version. It needs at least 6.8.9.10. If on Imagemagick 7, then change convert to magick. Also be sure you are using Imagemagick convert and not windows convert.

Comment: Thank you for the update to your post, I am using v7.0.8.56. Will edit this comment with results momentarily.

EDIT: Your updated syntax for Windows works perfectly, marked your post as the answer and upvoted. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey again! Sorry to return to this. I was using your command on my actual production images and realized something. Besides removing stray colored pixels surrounded by transparency, it's also replacing stray transparent pixels surrounded by color with a mean value. Is there a way to prevent this? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "with a mean value"? Do you not want all transparent pixels that are surrounded by any opaque color to be preserved?

Comment: I do want them to be preserved, and that's not happening with the current command. If a transparent pixel is fully surrounded by opaque pixels, it's being filled in with what appears to be a color determined by averaging the surrounding pixels, rather than left alone.

Comment: Correct with my old code. It does replace the transparency with the mean (average) color of the region. But I have changed the code to do what I think you want. So see my ADDITION in my answer.

Comment: Thanks again for the addition! This indeed solves the issue.

Answer (score 4):

fmw42's excellent answer uses connected regions, but I think it is possible with just a morphology. Use:

```
0 0 0 
0 1 0 
0 0 0
```

As the structuring element with erode and it'll detect 8-way connected isolated pixels. Now EOR that with your alpha and it'll make those pixels fully transparent (ie. remove them).

I don't know IM well enough to make you a command to do this :-( But with the [libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/) command-line it would be this to make a test image:

```
size=256

# sparse speckles for the alpha
vips gaussnoise t1.v $size $size
vips relational_const t1.v a.v more 200

# RGB noise 
vips gaussnoise r.v $size $size
vips gaussnoise g.v $size $size
vips gaussnoise b.v $size $size

# assemble and save
vips bandjoin "r.v g.v b.v a.v" x.png
```

Then to remove your stray pixels:

```
# make mask.mor, a file containing our structuring element
cat >mask.mor <<EOF
3 3 
0   0   0
0   255 0
0   0   0
EOF

# pull out the alpha channel
vips extract_band x.png a.v 3

# find isolated pixels
vips morph a.v t1.v mask.mor erode

# EOR with alpha to zap those pixels
vips boolean t1.v a.v t2.v eor

# extract rgb from original, then attach our modified alpha
vips extract_band x.png rgb.v 0 --n 3
vips bandjoin "rgb.v t2.v" x2.png
```

Here's before and after:

[image]

The libvips CLI is fast but a bit clumsy. It's neater if you use something like Python to script it.